# Can $\mathsf{Set}$ be seen as a (non-trivial) 2-category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

I know that $\mathsf{Rel}$ can be seen as a 2-category with inclusion of relations as 2-morphisms, when passing to $\mathsf{Set}$, relations become functions and inclusions are constrained to be "equalities" (see [Is $\mathsf{Set}$ a 2-category?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807036/is-set-a-2-category)), is there any other way where we can see $\mathsf{Set}$ as a non-trivial 2-category? If not, how can we prove that it cannot be other than a trivial 2-category?

Comment: Do you mean keeping functions as the arrows and just adding 2-arrows? If you put an equivalence relation on the hom sets that is preserved by composition (for instance generated by some interval objects and homotopy) then you get a 2-category. A non-locally-posetal example would be harder.

Comment: Yes that what I mean. The answer is then "yes", thanks

Comment: The inclusions $\mathsf{Set} \hookrightarrow \mathsf{Span}$ and $\mathsf{Set} \hookrightarrow \mathsf{Rel}$ form _proarrow equipments_, a sort of double-categorical structure, but the 2-dimensional structure all comes from $\mathsf{Span}$ / $\mathsf{Rel}$.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Could you elaborate on your description of a non-trivial 2-categorical structure? I don't see any sensible interval object in the category of sets.

Comment: @HeinrichD I didn't specify a _sensible_ interval object ;-) Thinking off the top of my head, fixing a regular cardinal $\kappa$, one could declare two functions $f,g$ to be equivalent if they are equal except on a subset of the source of cardinality less than $\kappa$. I believe this is an equivalence relation on hom-sets of $Set$ that is respected by composition, hence one gets an enrichment in equivalence relations. I'd have to think harder to get an example where the homs are not just equivalence relations. Perhaps do something drastic like well-order the universe and use that :-)

Comment: Here's a possibly stupid answer -- considering $Set$ as a Cartesian closed (thus monoidal closed) category, you can then consider it as a bicategory ("lax $2$-category) with a single object. This probably counts as "trivial" however, and thus doesn't answer the question, because even though the $2$-cells are non-trivial (what the author seemed to have in mind) the $0$-cell (singular, not plural) could reasonably be considered "trivial".

Answer (score 3):

There is a (not very interesting) construction which works for every category $\mathcal{C}$: Take any commutative monoid $M$. For parallel morphisms $f,g$ we define a $2$-morphism $f \to g$ to be some element of $M$ when $f=g$, and otherwise there is none. The composition of $2$-morphisms is the composition in $M$.

Comment: The first observation does not work: for arrow from $\{a,b\}$ to $\{a,b\}$ with $f(a)=f(b)=a$ $g(a)=a$,$g(b)=b$ one has $f \leqslant g$ but the restriction of $f$ and $g$ to $\{b \}$  does not satisfies $f \leqslant g$. (one can also argue that the second might be considered as a "trivial structure")

Comment: Thank you, I have erased the first paragraph. It would be interesting if every strict $2$-categorical structure on $\mathsf{Set}$ has this "trivial" monoid form. That monoid is the endo($2-$)morphism monoid of $\mathrm{id}_1$, where $1 \in \mathsf{Set}$ is the terminal object.

Comment: That's not very interesting, since the resulting 2-category will just be the product of the 1-category $\mathsf{Set}$ with the 2-category consisting of one object, its identity morphism, and $M$ as the 2-morphisms. Oh, and your $M$ must be commutative in order for the interchange law to hold.

Comment: You are right. Any other more interesting ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This should be a comment, but it's too long so there it is.

You could always define a new concept of arrows that probe deeper inside the inner structures of $Sets$. $Sets$ should actually be called "$Card$" (as category of cardinals).

Knowing that elements of sets are sets themselves, its not difficult to come up with some concepts of $2$-functions $f: A \rightarrow B$ seen as a pair $(g, (g_a))$, where $g: A \rightarrow B$ is an usual function of set, and $(g_a)$ is a family of functions such that $g_a:a \rightarrow g(a)$ for all $a$ in $A$. These $2$-functions would play the role of $1$-arrows in your $2$-category  $2$-$Sets$. Now, you have to find a natural definition for $2$-arrows (i.e., maps of $2$-functions). It surely can be done (I didn't try), and you could even be able to make $Sets$ into an $\omega$-category, that would actually encodes all the membership tree (thus being the "true" category of set theory).

You have to take care of empty set I think, but I guess it can be done.

edit: Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets, let us write a 2-map between $A$ and $B$ as $(f, f_a)$ with $f: A \rightarrow B$ and for each $a$ in $A$, a map $f_a: a \rightarrow f(a)$.
You can define a composition here as $(g, g_b) \circ (f, f_a) = (g \circ f, (g\circ f)_a = g_{f(a)} \circ f_a)$. This composition is associative, and identity is obviously given by $(Id_A, ({Id_A})_a = Id_a)$, turning the collection of sets where $1$-arrows are $2$-maps into a $1$-category. We now have to define $2$-arrows and show that the composition is functorial. Let us define a $2$-arrow $\eta: (f,f_a) \Rightarrow (g,g_a)$ as a collection of maps $\eta_a: f(a) \rightarrow g(a)$ for each $a$ in $A$, such that $\eta_a \circ f_a = g_a$. This is highly inspired from the concept of natural transformation as you might see. I'm going to check if this turn the above category as a $2$-cat (it should). The vertical composition is simply given by $(\xi \circ_1 \eta)_a = \xi_a \circ \eta_a$, making the collection of arrows between $2$-maps between two fixed sets a $1$-cat as it should be. It is left to define an horizontal composition and verify the functoriality.

Note that the initial element is given by the empty set and that if $(f,f_a)$ is a $2$-map between $A$ and $B$ with empty set in the image of $f$, then the empty set is necessarily an element of $A$ with $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$.

Comment: I don't understand this construction. $2$-morphisms should be defined between $1$-morphisms (here: maps of sets), not objects (here: sets).

Comment: Ok, this terminology is a little bit confusing. Also, I assume that the OP wanted to have as $1$-morphisms the usual maps of sets, i.e. preserve the $1$-morphisms of $\mathsf{Set}$. Since the question was about a $2$-categorical structure on $\mathsf{Set}$.

Comment: You have no choice if you want to have some meaningful 2-category of sets: the higher layers of arrows are probing the higher inner structure of your objects (i.e., map of sets are probing the first layer of your set, which is its cardinality. You should expect that a meaningful concept of map of maps would probe the cardinality of the elements). To do so in a natural way, you have to change the 1-arrows as I did. I still have to check that the Godement's law can be adapted to this definition (it doesn't seem automatic, but I'm  confident).

Comment: But if you just want keep sets as objects, $\mathsf{Rel}$ and $\mathsf{Span}$ would also be candidates.

Comment: Would it be possible to clarify how this approach differs from either (1) using as 2-cells commuting squares of functions (i.e. the morphisms in the "arrow category" or "morphism category" corresponding to set https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/arrow+category ) ? (2) take the sub(-2-)category of the category of all small categories https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cat consisting only of discrete categories -- then functors are basically functions, and natural transformations between those functors basically commutative squares? Are the functions $\eta_a$ between singletons $\{f(a)\} \to \{g(a)\}$?